# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tttttt'

Tags: python, odoo

I have a problem with that code. What's wrong whit it?

```
class test(osv.osv):
    _name = "test"    
    _description = "uuuu"    

    def tttttt():
        return "testtt"

test() 

instance = test()
print (instance.tttttt())
```

Comment: also, why not `def tttttt(self):`?

Comment: why are the names so unreadable? maybe this is your problem? try using simpler names.

Comment: I Especially made an simple example like this one to simplify the code. Normally, this is for an One hundred lines i'm trying to debug...

Comment: try and you will have my error, I tried everything, with self and without, during 4 last hours and it didn't work..

Comment: What line are you getting the error on?  At least according to http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/object_attributes.html there is no `_description` field, so you could well be getting that exception from some code internal to the `osv` module.  Please provide your stack trace.

Comment: Did you try this code ? It works ? no. You will have the following error : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tttttt'

Comment: If the class doesn't herit of osv.osv, everythings will work. BUT I need to use this line : self.pool.get('prestashop.config').search(cr, uid, [('id', '>', 0)]) to get the prestashopconfiguration. And when i put this line, I have an other error : argument missing(pool, cr, uid)...(this is why a herit of osv.osv..)

Comment: No, I didn't, because I'm not going to install the `osv` package to debug your code for you.  I just provided you with some feedback that could help to track down your problem, and asked you to meet me half way by doing a simple copy paste.  If you can't do that, you don't deserve help.

Comment: Where's the full stacktrace? Is this the full code? Note that `NoneType`  shouldn't have arbitrary properties. What's odd is that if this is your real code, you shouldn't have a `None` returned from a class construction call.

Comment: Precisely.  Because the `osv` package is probably using a metaclass to reprocess all class members that have names starting with an underscore, but if you provide it a name it doesn't recognize, it chokes trying to do an assignment internally or something.  If you posted a stack trace, we would likely find that out quite quickly.

Comment: Sorry I'm quiete annyed because of that :/. So I will send you my real code. And the stacktrace linked to it. I hope it will be better to you.

Comment: We don't need the real code necessarily, just the stack trace from your example.  All we (or at least I) want to see right now is if the attribute error is coming from your code or code internal to the `osv` module.  And where did you read that `_description` should work?  The docs I see for `osv` don't mention that field name.

Comment: I can post expept a commnet ...

Comment: Edit the original question instead.  Also, why are you using this library?  They seem to have made some questionable design decisions...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935464/nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-languages     here :)

Comment: I need "pool, cr, uid" args to browse data from my database

Comment: Yeah, but there are other Python ORMs out there.

Comment: I'm working on python and openerp for 1months.. That the problems.. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. After some digging, it seems that the OpenERP framework has done some strange things with the object creation mechanism. For subclasses of `BaseModel` like `osv.osv` and your class, the [`__new__()` method](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-server/6.1/view/4261/openerp/osv/orm.py#L922) just registers that class in the pool and returns `None`.

You can confirm this by slightly modifying your print statement.

```
instance = test()
print instance is None # will print True.
```

As far as I know, OpenERP model classes can't run outside the server process. If you're trying to write unit tests or something, you either have to write separate helper classes and test those, or run full-scale integration tests with the [YAML testing framework](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/contribute/15_guidelines/coding_guidelines_testing.html).

For an example of testing helper classes, see our [`product_stockouts`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~zaber/openobject-addons/zaber-custom/files/head:/product_stockouts/) module. The `sim_*` classes are helpers with unit tests, and they all get called by the model classes in `product_stockouts.py`.